# RHEL6 yum 'ascii' codec can't decode

Tags: redhat, yum

I went to upgrade my RHEL5 to RHEL6, without problem. I've got just a little cosmetic warning as :

```
# yum update
Modules complémentaires chargés : product-id, security, subscription-manager
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The ascii message doesn't come out when I did :

```
#export LANG=
# yum update
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

That's meaning is local problem. How to fix it ? What' kind of package I need?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What are your system's locale settings? Run `locale` and post the output.

Comment: The problem is gone, I don't know how :-/